# Search.list method of Youtube API seems unable to respond correctly to reasonable search query

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

According to Google support for YouTube is provided through this site where Google people answer questions here. So this is addressed at those who are supposed to provide support for YouTube API.

I apologize to others who read this because it might reflect our frustration regarding this issue the likes of which can be concidered reasonable expectation of Search API

I asked the same question as part of yt-dlp but as usual I got lectures about bypassing georestricted videos which is really trivial nowdays. But no answer to the problem..Why everyone equates retrieving georestriction information with bypassing solutions?

We have been trying to use the Search.list method to provide us with say 5 (video_id/url)s that are banned in a given country code say India or Malasia. We have tried to include iq to pass the query but it runs and returns nothing.

This is surprising because in Google Youtube API documentation refers to similar situation a comon use cases.

So, I would be most grateful if a youtube support personnel would respond that:

1. At least confirm that this sort of queries are beyond the Search API's scope, OR
2. How this can be done without referring a charater string like 'cat' or 'dog'

I was not getting any support from Google, Youtube or community. Although on https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support it is claimed that the Youtube developers respond to questions on this side.
I am hoping one of those YouTube API experts would respond to this question.

Comment: As far as I know YouTube staff don't come on Stack Overflow since years. Using [their bug tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=youtube%2Fv3) might be the way to go if you want to discuss with YouTube staff.

Comment: I assure you that is what they told me only a couple of weeks ago. Although I tend to believe you.

Comment: They indeed say that they come on Stack Overflow help people like you "How to Get Help: We support the YouTube Data API on Stack Overflow. Google engineers monitor and answer questions with the youtube-api, youtube-data-api, and youtube-v3-api tags." (Source: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support) but this is a false statement since years resulting in taking advantage of volunteers like me.

Comment: I actually haven't seen that you were aware of this URL before sharing it to you my bad.

Comment: Well, good news; it seems that it has been accepted as a bug and feasable and it is hopefully being sorted out according to the bug tracker.
Apparently, it is possible to get a listing of videos allowed in a given region. I can think of that many uses for that since the list is going to be very very long unless there is other limiting factors.
Thanks, Benjamin. It seems to have paid off.

Comment: Please comment the bug tracker issue link.

Comment: The status seems to have changed. According to this link https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/277166589, they claim that it is not possible to fix it despite being classified as a bug.

Initially the person responsible notified me that an application has been made to fix it. Then the change was carried out but not the one I expected. 
Apparently, it can not be fixed. It is ridiculous, especially that the inverted search is possible: i.e. you can search for all the videos allowed given a region code but not the blocked ones. I have kind of protested but so far no response.

Comment: Maybe if others joined in they might do something. I don't believe that it is not possible to fix it. It is surely a simple SQL query if you have access to the database.

Comment: I haven't paid much attention to the bug tracker as they close each issue by qualifying it as a bug which is infeasible to be fixed which doesn't make sense. I think they keep it open to make sure someone doesn't share by mistake a zero day vulnerability. As far as I know the only workaround would be about searching videos by not taking first into account georestriction but then verify with a VPN in the given country if the given video is still accessible.

Comment: I think you are right. They will fix it but until then they define it as not fixable.
The return set will be just too long if you have no other limiting factor except geo-restriction.